# Search for a or b in a string - Javascript

Tags: javascript, search, indexof

How can I search if my string contains a or b or c in JavaScript?

I need to test if string contains "is" or "test" or "string".

```
var string = "This is my test string to search";
var result = string.indexOf("is"||"test"||"string");
```

but it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
str.search(/is|test|string/)
```

Comment: No explanation, just searches for those words.

Answer (score 3):

It is better to use regular expression here:

```
if ( /is|test|string/.test(string) ) { ... }
```

However, if you want to search for words, I'd suggest to use special character `\b`.

**REF:** https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Comment: Please provide a reason for downvoting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**`String.search`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search). Search for a regular expression in the given string.

```
var str = "This is a sample text";
var re = /nothing|text|string/g
if (str.search(re) != -1) {
    midstring = " contains ";
} else {
    midstring = " does not contain ";
}
alert(str+ midstring + re);
```

Here is a [**`fiddled`**](http://jsfiddle.net/gopinaghr/7Xm72/1/) version.

Answer (score 0):

```
var string = "This is my test string to search";
string.match(/is|test|string/g);
```